# What happened to Captain Yamato by the end of Naruto story?

Tags: naruto

Well, the title is pretty much self-explanatory. What happened to him? Did he die from being used as a fertilizer for the white Zetsus? Or he's alive, like Mitarashi Anko is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He survived. In 699 you see him emerge from the Infinite Tsukuyomi. Spiral zetsu is near him and tries to grab him again, but the zetsu quickly falls apart (presumably it died).

You don't see him anywhere in 700, though. So it's unknown if he lived to that point or what he did after the IT was dispelled.

Comment: During the credits of The Last: Naruto the Movie, Yamato can be seen at a wedding taking place at least two years after the IT ended. Yamato also appears in Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring, which takes place several years later.

Answer (score 4):

he survived..
naruto gaiden the seventh hokage episode 7 page 8
[image]